# crontab does not get the log in log file

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cron, dockerfile

I have batch program and i do get some data from one server and update the data in my database and i want to trigger my batch program for every 15 mins. For that i use the crontab concept, i just open the crontab with the command

```
crontab -e

//i add the command in that crontab

15 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar xxxxxx.jar >> /var/log/cron.log
```

finally after that my batch program is not running and i did not get log in cron.log. whether it will automatically run the batch program or we have to trigger it

Answer (score 1):

The crontab isn't running every 15 min; it's running on the 15th of an hour.  If you'd like it to run every 15 minutes of an hour, change the crontab to:

0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar xxxxxx.jar >> /var/log/cron.log

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab entry will run the command at 15th minute of every hour. The command will run at 1:15, 2:15 and so on.

To run the program every 15 minutes, please use the following line

`*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar xxxxxx.jar > /var/log/cron.log`